# How to write into APCu from CLI-call?

Tags: php, nginx, command-line-interface, apc, apcu

I want to prefill my APCu-Cache with translation and there is already a job that does this called "SeedTranslationCacheJob". 
All jobs are only available in our "CRM" so a user that visits our website cannot start such jobs.

I call this job on each website-server-node to prefill the translations each node needs by cli:

```
php index.php job DeploymentJob --deploymentJobList="SeedTranslationCacheJob,TestTranslationCacheJob"
```

But this job does not fill the APCu even i have enabled CLI-Caching https://secure.php.net/manual/en/apcu.configuration.php#ini.apcu.enable-cli

Is there a way to fill the APCu that a web-request uses by a script called from cli? Or are these 2 complete different caches?

Is there perhaps a way to configure APCu that i can store data from cli-calls into it and that read them from web-request?

Answer (score 2):

This not possible to access the APCu data from a web-request that a cli script has written in. Even different cli calls cannot share data using APCu.